# How can I escape double quotes in content gotten from file

Tags: bash

I am trying to escape double quotes when adding content from `statusfile.log` to`statusfile_truncated.log`.

I have looked around and are just getting more confused. How would you achieve it?

This is what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

statusfile="statusfile.log"
statusfile_truncated="statusfile_truncated.log"
tail -n 50 $statusfile >> $statusfile_truncated
```

Content of statusfile.log:

```
2017-05-15 22:36:18 test.somedomain.com <--- 250 CWD successful. "/xxxxxxxxxxxxx" is current directory.
2017-05-15 22:36:18 test.somedomain.com <--- 250 CWD successful. "/xxxxxxxxxxxxx" is current directory.
2017-05-15 22:36:18 test.somedomain.com <--- 250 CWD successful. "/xxxxxxxxxxxxx" is current directory.
```

Content of statusfile_truncated.log should be:

```
2017-05-15 22:36:18 test.somedomain.com <--- 250 CWD successful. \"/xxxxxxxxxxxxx\" is current directory.
2017-05-15 22:36:18 test.somedomain.com <--- 250 CWD successful. \"/xxxxxxxxxxxxx\" is current directory.
2017-05-15 22:36:18 test.somedomain.com <--- 250 CWD successful. \"/xxxxxxxxxxxxx\" is current directory.
```

Comment: Please show us examples of your input and the expected output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I you just want to insert a backslash in front of the double quote you could go with `sed` like this:

```
sed 's/"/\\"/g' $statusfile >> $statusfile_truncated
```

But if there is to be real escaping going on there is other tools and techniques that should be considered.

Comment: This can also be used together with `tail` as a pipeline: `tail -n 50 $statusfile | sed 's/"/\\"/g' >> $statusfile_truncated`. BTW, I agree with the note about "real escaping"; this sounds suspiciously like a partial solution to a larger problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to quote a string in `bash` is to use the `%b` option in `printf`.  This will handle all special chars:

```
$ variablename='foo "bar and C:\\foo\\bar'
$ printf '%b\n' "$variablename"
foo "bar and C:\foo\bar
```

Comment: bash's printf `%b` format escapes and/or quotes strings *suitably for interpretation by bash*. If the string will be interpreted by something other than bash (even a different shell), that will sometimes produce completely inappropriate output. In order to quote/escape a string properly, you *need* to know how it's going to be parsed, and what parsing rules it'll be subject to.